# jQuery Facebook Share Image Issues

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying append Facebook share function into my web site using jQuery. According to Facebook developer manual, my problem is when I share any article, Facebook share it yes, but without picture **and for the best of cases with the wrong one**.

What I am doing:

1. Appending Facebook meta Tags into header where I defined title, picture, on so on
2. Share button into body

Then I am using my js code to append that code into body code.

```
var url = 'http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?s=100&p[url]='+encodeURIComponent(url)+'&p[title]='+title+'&p[summary]='+summary+'&p[images][0]='+pic;
```

Comment: jquery is a library for DOM manipulation, not sure why you would want to use it for a sharing function?

Comment: Thank you for answering, I am using jQuery to append share buttons and Facebook meta, I am appending those metas using my external js located into my server and that js file will be called by a third web site users.

Answer (score 0):

- You can´t dynamically change the metatags, because Facebook does not call JavaScript. Metatags must be available in the head section on startup.
- The sharer.php only allowes one parameter, with the url: `https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=[your-urlencoded-url]` - The share dialog takes the OG data from the URL.

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently using this Open Graph tags, and they works, i have changed the connection to database in php to the `<header>` section of the page, without the  "og:image:width" and "og:image:height" tags, the first time the article is shared, no image is shown, due to a Facebook cache problem.

```
<meta property="og:image" content="/path/to/image" />
<meta property="og:image:width" content="image_width_in_pixels" />
<meta property="og:image:height" content="image-height_in_pixels" />
<meta property="og:url" content="url_being_shared" />
<meta property="og:type" content="article" />
<meta property="og:title" content="title_of_article" />
<meta property="og:description" content="description_of_article" />
```